Switching between two power sources and charging a battery pack
I am designing a circuit, which can use either the power from the normal socket (230V) to charge a battery pack and power a arduno uno R3 at the same time when a spst switch is on. When the switch is still on but i am not connected to the normal socket then i want to use the current from the battery pack. If the switch is off then the arduino shouldn t be powered at all. Here is what i have so far:
I have a transformer from 230V to 12VAC (18 W) which is connected to a rectifing bridge which is outputting a 16VDC. Then i have connected from the output of the bridge in parallel 2 capacitors of 47uF and 10uF for filtering. In parallel as well is connected a buck converter (from 16 to 12.6V) then connected to a bms module (3S, 8A). To the bms module is connected a battery pack made from 3 in series 18850 li-ion batteries. Then in series i have a LM7805 voltage regulator to output 5V to the arduino. From the hot wire from the voltage regulator is a switch on/off to the arduino. What i tought so far is to connect a relay from the output of the LM7805 with a flyback diode and the output of the relay coil to the collector of a c945 transistor. The base of the transistor i wanted to connect i would connect it to a 1kohm resistance and then to the hot wire before the LM7805. The emmiter i would had connected to the ground.
Would this scheme work?


After the wall of text there is a question will it work, and the answer is no, that thing is dangerous if you connect a buck regulator to batteries. Can you tell me why do people always leave out the lithium battery charger and try to directly connect to a voltage supply?

It was a project from the school i go to try and make a power supply that will power the arduino and charge the batteries so they can power the arduino in the abscence of the current from the socket. How something like this could be achieved?

Batteries are charged with a battery charger. A BMS is not a battery charger. A buck converter is not a battery charger. And, improperly handled lithium batteries get degraded and damaged and when damaged they may explode or burst into flames. You need a battery charger that will make sure the lithium batteries are safely charged until they are full and charging must stop before they are overcharged.
